# How to end a while loop with a variable inside the loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Hey I'm fairly new to programming and I have a challenge that I just can't figure out entirely. I need to figure out how long it will take for someone to pay off a credit plan with a set interest rate and payment rate. There are two parts of this code I can't seem to figure out. The first is how to stop the while loop when the endingBalance equals 0. Since I can't use endingBalance in the while conditions I'm not sure how to stop it so I just put in a placeholder of 24. The other issue I'm having is how to have the endingBalance stop from going into the negatives. I think I need to make a if statement for the principle to equal the starting balance when the starting balance is less than the principle but at this point I'm not sure how to do that. I just need some help on these two problems and any help would be appreciated.

```
DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE = 0.1
INTEREST_RATE = 0.12
PAYMENT_RATE = 0.05
balance = price - (price * DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE)
payment = balance * PAYMENT_RATE
print("%0s%18s%13s%13s%12s%16s" % \
    ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest", "Principle", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))
count = 1
while count != 24:
    interest = balance * INTEREST_RATE / 12
    principle = payment - interest
    endingBalance = balance - principle 
    print("%2d%14.2f%18.2f%13.2f%12.2f%12.2f" % \
        (count, balance, interest, principle, payment, endingBalance)) 
    balance = endingBalance
    if balance > principle:
        principle = principle
    else:
        principle = balance
    count += 1
```

Comment: `while balance > 0:`?

Comment: `if(endingBalance==0)
break` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the condition in your `while` loop as below:

```
DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE = 0.1
INTEREST_RATE = 0.12
PAYMENT_RATE = 0.05
balance = price - (price * DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE)
payment = balance * PAYMENT_RATE
print("%0s%18s%13s%13s%12s%16s" % \
    ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest", "Principle", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))
count = 1
endingBalance = balance
while endingBalance > 0:
    interest = balance * INTEREST_RATE / 12
    principle = payment - interest
    endingBalance = balance - principle
    if endingBalance <= 0:
        break
    print("%2d%14.2f%18.2f%13.2f%12.2f%12.2f" % \
        (count, balance, interest, principle, payment, endingBalance)) 
    balance = endingBalance
    if balance > principle:
        principle = principle
    else:
        principle = balance
    count += 1
```

with the above condition in `while` loop the loop will execute only till `endingBalance` is `>0` and also will never be a negative value

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, you have to change your while loop. In addition if you do not want a negative ending balance, you should chance the line `principle = payment - interest`.

```
price=2000
DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE = 0.1
INTEREST_RATE = 0.12
PAYMENT_RATE = 0.05
balance = price - (price * DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE)
payment = balance * PAYMENT_RATE
print("%0s%18s%13s%13s%12s%16s" % \
    ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest", "Principle", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))
count = 1
while balance>0:
    interest = balance * INTEREST_RATE / 12
    principle = min(payment - interest,balance)
    endingBalance = balance - principle 
    print("%2d%14.2f%18.2f%13.2f%12.2f%12.2f" % \
        (count, balance, interest, principle, payment, endingBalance)) 
    balance = endingBalance
    if balance > principle:
        principle = principle
    else:
        principle = balance
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare 'endingBalance' out side while loop with any random +ve integer at first because it is not going to effect anything.
Because inside while loop its going to change irrespective of its initial value

```
DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE = 0.1
INTEREST_RATE = 0.12
PAYMENT_RATE = 0.05
balance = price - (price * DOWN_PAYMENT_RATE)
payment = balance * PAYMENT_RATE
print("%0s%18s%13s%13s%12s%16s" % \
    ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest", "Principle", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))
count = 1
endingBalance = 100
while endingBalance > 0:
    interest = balance * INTEREST_RATE / 12
    principle = payment - interest
    endingBalance = balance - principle 
    print("%2d%14.2f%18.2f%13.2f%12.2f%12.2f" % \
        (count, balance, interest, principle, payment, endingBalance)) 
    balance = endingBalance
    if balance > principle:
        principle = principle
    else:
        principle = balance
    count += 1
```